# MySQL LIKE... Result Priority Sorting

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, case, sql-like

So I decided to make search in MySQL using...

```
SELECT * 
FROM items AS i 
INNER JOIN tags AS t ON i.id = t.item_id 
WHERE item LIKE ('%s%' OR '%s2%' ... OR '%sn%') 
  AND tag LIKE ('%s%' OR '%s2%' ... OR '%sn%');
```

It's not fulltext, item is VARCHAR(32), tag is VARCHAR(16).

I have problem ordering results... I can get priorities straight when it comes to one search string, but when I have more, it got a little bit bullshit and I end up with (number of search strings)+7 queries and I feel really dirty using it. I feel more dirty than bathing in shit using it actually... This is how it does look like...

```
SELECT 
    t1.item_id, t1.item, t1.created, t1.owner, t1.type, t1.fld, t2.tag
FROM 
    items AS t1
INNER JOIN 
    tagged AS t2 ON t1.item_id = t2.item_id
WHERE 
    (item LIKE '%red%' OR '%apple%')
GROUP BY 
    item_id
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
       WHEN item = 'red'
         THEN 0 
       WHEN item = 'apple'
         THEN 1 
       WHEN (item LIKE 'red%' OR 'apple%')
         THEN 2 
       WHEN (item LIKE '%red%' AND '%apple%') 
        AND (tag LIKE '%red%' AND '%apple%')
        THEN 3 
      WHEN (item LIKE '%red%' AND '%apple%')
       AND (tag LIKE '%red%' OR '%apple%')
        THEN 4 
      WHEN (item LIKE '%red%' AND '%apple%')
        THEN 5 
      WHEN (item LIKE '%red%' OR '%apple%')
       AND (tag LIKE '%red%' OR '%apple%')
        THEN 6 
      WHEN (item LIKE '%red%' OR '%apple%')
        THEN 7 
      WHEN (tag LIKE '%red%' OR '%apple%')
        THEN 8 
      ELSE 9 
    END ASC , 
    created DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Yea, it's that dirty, how can I cut it down? I actually use PHP script that generate that query from search strings. That query it is only a little bit slower, than that query without ordering, and we don't get high loads, but it feels to dirty for me. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: it's worth mentioning that a leading wildcard search is about the slowest thing you can ask SQL to do. For stuff like this in particular, you'd be better off with a dedicated search tool like Sphinx.

Comment: Can't do that, webshosting doesn't support :/

Comment: okay. Well, as long as you're aware of the performance implications of queries like `%xyz%`. The DB will have to read every single record in the table to find the matching records, so if you have a large amount of data (or even a moderate amount), this will seriously slow down your performance. All those additional pattern matches in the `WHERE` clause will also hit your performance, although the inital read will be the main issue.

Comment: So, is there a way to get faster results with just query? No search engine or anything...

Comment: in the absence of FULLTEXT or any kind of specialised search tool, it's a lot harder. That's why these search tools exist; plain SQL searching just isn't up to the job. The typical solution is to use a tagging system instead, so that users search for tags rather than words embedded in the main item text, but it looks like you've already got a tagging system in place, so not sure what to suggest beyond that.

Comment: Can I make fulltext search on varchar columns? And is it effective?

Comment: No, fulltext wouldn't be effective here; it's only useful for words longer than 4 characters; shorter words are filtered out. It probably also wouldn't find partial words in the way that it looks like you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to push the case...when to select clause. My query will look something like this:

```
SELECT field1, field2,
case 
 when field1 like 's1%' then 1
 when field1 like 's2%' then 2
end as ordering_field
from table_name
group by field1
order by ordering_field
```